# Getting below error even after implementing AppendTableStream Interface in apache flink

Tags: java, dynamic, apache-flink

I have written the simple sample to sink the table but getting this exception in Apache Flink even after implementing AppendTableSink Interface.

```
    package com.cc.flink.functionUtils;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.IterationRuntimeContext;
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFunction;
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.io.OutputFormat;
    import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.LocalCollectionOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
    import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TupleTypeInfo;
    import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
    import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.DataStreamUtils;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.RMQSource;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.common.RMQConnectionConfig;
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
    import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment;
    import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.AppendStreamTableSink;
    import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.RetractStreamTableSink;
    import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.TableSink;
    import org.apache.flink.types.Row;




    public class MyTable implements AppendStreamTableSink<Row>{



        @Override
        public TableSink<Row> configure(String[] arg0, TypeInformation<?>[] arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getFieldNames() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<?>[] getFieldTypes() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<Row> getOutputType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void emitDataStream(DataStream<Row> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.print();

        }




        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            final RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
                    .setHost("localhost")
                    .setVirtualHost("/")
                    .setUserName("guest")
                    .setPassword("guest")
                    .setPort(5672)
                    .build();


            final DataStream<String> stream = env
                    .addSource(new RMQSource<String>(
                            connectionConfig,            // config for the RabbitMQ connection
                            "test",                 // name of the RabbitMQ queue to consume
                            true,                        // use correlation ids; can be false if only at-least-once is required
                            new SimpleStringSchema()))   // deserialization schema to turn messages into Java objects
                    .setParallelism(1);   



            final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            StreamTableEnvironment StreamTableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
            Table fromDataStream = StreamTableEnv.fromDataStream(stream,
                    "member_id");
            StreamTableEnv.registerTable("emp1",fromDataStream);
            Table output =StreamTableEnv.sql("select count(*) from emp1 where member_id Like '%test%'");
            fromDataStream.writeToSink(new MyTable() );
            env.execute();

        }

    }
```

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.calcite.sql.parser).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Stream Tables can only be emitted by AppendStreamTableSink, RetractStreamTable
>
> at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableenvironment.writeToSink (StreamTableenvironment.scala:219)
>
> at org.apache.flink.table.api.Table.writeToSink (table.scala:800)
>
> at org.apache.flink.table.api.Table.writeToSink(table.scala:773)
>
> at com.cc.flink.functionutils.MyTable.main(MyTable.java:103)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your example is that you are trying to use an `AppendTableSink` but your query produces retractions. This is due to the `COUNT(*)` in your statement. Whenever a new row arrives the old emitted count is not valid anymore and needs to be retracted.

If it would just be a `SELECT *`, than every incoming row would produce exactly one output row that does not affect previous rows.

Comment: Hi twalthr                                                                                               Thanks for the reply, if you see the code i am trying to sink the table named "fromDataStream " not the table named "output".first i tried to implement the retractTableSink it wont work then i tried to implement appendTableSink & tried to sink the fromDataStream but got the same error in the both cases

Comment: @twalthr but how to get around this ? if we want to insert distinct vales into CSV sink it failes with similar error so what would be the solution ?

Comment: In most cases you could also use time-based operations like windowing. I would also recommend this talk and exercises here: https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/wiki/Querying-Dynamic-Tables-with-SQL